# getting java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero when counting the number of selects

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I'm using Java to access an Oracle Database.

I've created a SQL function which calculates a user's feedback, based on his transactions (purchases or sales).

The feedback values are stored in the table `TRANSACCOES`. The function works fine when I update the feedback column, but when I recalculate the feedback right after a "removal" (I don't really delete it, just set a flag to deleted) I get an error: `ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero.`

If after that error I do an update on another transaction it recalculates just fine. So I don't know why this happens.

Here is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calcula_classificacao (id_user NUMBER
                     ) RETURN FLOAT AS
counter NUMBER;
sumvendr FLOAT;
sumcompr FLOAT;
f FLOAT;
f1 FLOAT;

BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(t.ID_TRANSACCAO) INTO counter 
    FROM TRANSACCOES t 
    JOIN ARTIGOS a 
      ON a.ID_ARTIGO = t.ID_ARTIGO 
   WHERE ((t.ID_COMPRADOR = id_user AND t.FEEDBACK_COMPRADOR >= 0) 
           OR (id_user = a.ID_VENDEDOR AND t.FEEDBACK_VENDEDOR >= 0)) 
     AND t.ELIMINADO = 0;

  SELECT SUM(t.FEEDBACK_COMPRADOR) INTO sumcompr 
    FROM TRANSACCOES t 
    JOIN ARTIGOS a 
      ON a.ID_ARTIGO = t.ID_ARTIGO 
   WHERE t.ID_COMPRADOR = id_user 
     AND t.ELIMINADO = 0 
     AND t.FEEDBACK_COMPRADOR >= 0;

  SELECT SUM(t.FEEDBACK_VENDEDOR) INTO sumvendr 
    FROM TRANSACCOES t 
    JOIN ARTIGOS a 
      ON a.ID_ARTIGO = t.ID_ARTIGO 
   WHERE id_user = a.ID_VENDEDOR 
     AND t.ELIMINADO = 0 
     AND t.FEEDBACK_VENDEDOR >= 0;

IF (sumvendr IS NULL) THEN
   sumvendr := 0;
END IF;

IF (sumcompr IS  NULL) THEN
   sumcompr := 0;
END IF;

sumvendr := sumvendr + sumcompr;
f := (sumvendr*100);
f1 := f/counter;

UPDATE utilizadores SET classificacao = f1 WHERE id_utilizador = id_user;

   RETURN f1;
END;
```

Comment: after removal the first query i not satisfying so the count becomes 0

Comment: @Srinivas I know that, but can't understand why it returns zero immediately after the removal. Because, when I run it afterwards it works.

Comment: @ferozakbar can you be a little more specific? because it works if i run the function after the removal method is finished. thanks

Comment: The problem, like said it before, is on this line f/counter, maybe after removing your id_TRANSACCAO stays only with rows where the elements are set to was deleted. Therefore making counter = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem. I was testing the function with many purchases from a user but the sellers only had a sell. So when I was deleting a purchase, I was deleting the only sell of a seller. So, since the function wasn't preventing the fact of being the last sell/purchase of a user, it was getting that error. Because when it recalculates, it recalculates the feedbacks of both users involved in the transaction.